# Detect if an HTML table has been pasted into a textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, textarea

I was wondering if there was a way to detect (or at least make a good assumption) whether text pasted into a textarea includes content copied from an HTML table?

I'm finding users of my website are pasting tabular data (from other websites) into their comments and I'm wanting to clean up the way my website displays those comments.

I'm using PHP, but I'm not too fussed if there's a way to do this with Javascript.

And bonus points if your suggestion can keep the table formatting :)

Comment: use the if (isset()) {} function

Comment: @Max please clarify, i'm not sure how isset relates to the issue

Comment: Well you could fo something like this: if (!isset $table) {you shall not pass;} and then go like this:
if (isset $table) {echo "Thank you";}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure textarea can't receive formatted content. If your users copy a table, div, or whatever HTML structure from other sites and paste into a textarea, you'll have access only to the pure visible text of the copied content, not the HTML code. Using a textarea, the only way to paste HTML code is if your user copy the code directly =).

An alternative is to use a WYSIWYG like [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) or [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), it can retain rich text and you'll be able to get the HTML that your users paste there.

Or you can simplify and use the attribute contenteditable with other tag (like a div) and test if there's a table using a Regex, this way:

```
<div id="yourDiv" contenteditable>Paste a table here!!</div>

var yourHTML = document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML;
var thereIsATableHere = /<table[^>]*>(.*?)<\/table>/.test(yourHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks! The WYSIWYG editor was the way I was fearing I'd have to go, but I think the contenteditable suggestion will do just enough for what I need